# Adding 3px indent (padding) on top of cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to add 2 or 3 pixel blank space at the top of all cells.
but "Format Cell" doesn't have any indent for top.

(I don't want space on the top and on the bottom be the same like what center in vertical alignment does.)

I want to know is there any solution to add this 3px top padding to cells?

It doesn't matter that you use macro or any third party tools.

Comment: Sadly, Excel doesn't have this built in.  My own workaround is to insert a very thin, empty row above.  Or you could install an add-in, see https://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/where-is-cell-padding/where-is-cell-padding.html.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to make the row(s) 3px taller and bottom-align all your cells.

Ways to change the row height include:

- Click on the border between two row labels:

  [image]

  and drag it down (or up). 
  Or
- Select the row and type one of the following key sequences:

  - <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, or
  - <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>

  and then type a new row height value.

Answer (score 1):

If you won't mind doing it cell by cell, you can use Alt + Enter and adjust the font size of the created blank line.

DETAILS:

1. Place your cursor in the beginning of your cell data;
2. Press Alt + Enter to create a blank line;
3. Put the cursor in the created blank line by pressing Up Arrow Key;
4. Press Shift + Left Arrow key to highlight an invisible space;
5. Adjust the font size of the highlighted space to 3 or any size of your choice

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Rajesh Sinha's answer, create a column and input any text, with auto fit row height, increase font size of the created column.

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't supports Cell padding.

But yes, up to certain extend this can be manged by using **Alignments** & **Indent**.

*You may try this trick also:*

- Select Cell Range & increase the Font's size.
- Apply **Auto fit.**
- Finally, reverse the Font size.

*This will create Cell padding look.*

Comment: I don't like that this would change column widths as well, leaving them wider than necessary.

Comment: @AdamV,, the object was Padding Cell with White Spaces never increase size !!